# Creating a plugin bundle for iOS using XCode

Tags: ios, plugins, bundle, project-template

How do I create a plugin bundle for iOS in XCode? When I try to create a new project, in "choose your template for new project" under iOS I can see only the types "Application" and "Library". There is only one template under "Library", the "Cocoa Touch Static Library".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic linking is not allowed by Apple for iOS projects (only against iOS-provided libraries), which is why you can't find a corresponding project. If you try to use dynamic linking, your app gets rejected.

Comment: What about asset bundles then?

Comment: This is a Unity3D feature, it seems. And I'm willing to bet that it doesn't contain any code, only resource files.